# Why is my function of type 'a list list -> ... rather than 'a list?

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec slice l i k = 
  match l with
    h::t -> 
      if (k == 0) then h 
      else if (i == 0) then h @ (slice t 0 (k-1)) 
      else slice t (i-1) (k-1);;
```

When I enter `slice [1; 2; 3; 4] 1 2;;` I get:

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type 'a list
```

however if I enter `slice [[1]; [2]; [3]; [4]] 1 2;;` it works as intended. I don't understand why OCaml thinks l is a list of lists of 'a, and not just a standard list of 'a?

Answer (score 4):

I see two problems. In your first case you return `h`. But you should be returning a list, and `h` is the first element of your list.

In your second case you use the `@` operator, which expects a list on both sides. But `h` is the first element of your list, not a list. You can fix this by using `::` instead of `@`.

Other problems:

I don't see a place where you handle an empty list `l`.

You should use `=` rather than `==`. The `==` operator in OCaml is for very special purposes only. For day-to-day equality comparisons you want to use `=`.